# Funny results on Profile>Reputation>by time

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Did you *just* roll out a change to the
Profile > Reputation > by time
list?  I’m seeing funny results in [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/885/jd%C5%82ugosz?tab=reputation).  The count of events and twirldown is missing, and a single time is attached to a line that might say something like “171 upvote” which is clearly many events.

[image: screenshot]

This is Chrome on an Android tablet.

Comment: Screenshot? Browser/OS and versions?

Comment: How are you sorting the page? By post or by time?

Comment: Also, what site are you seeing this on?

Comment: @Oded it is so-labeled in the Title and in the body.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean - do you sort by post or by time, as illustrated here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaMT7.png ?

Comment: @Oded if I say “by time” again will you know what I mean?  How do you not know what I mean when you’re asking for thise exact same words?

Comment: Because you are not using those words. You say "it is so-labeled", when I don't see your sort order in the screenshot. If you see what words I use - why not use those words too?

Comment: What is funny about the results? Looks totally fine.

Comment: @Oded  the text reads `Profile > Reputation > by time` that is the sequence of nested view structures, **including** the sorting one as the last to press to get to the screen.  It's in the Title.  It's in the body.  Thus, I'm wondering why you asked.  Understand?

Comment: @ShadowWizard so I'm learning… before it was exqctly like “by post” but sorted differently and with a slight difference in column width.  Though twirling down would give wrong results if it’s multiply listed (showing the *entire* group, not the fraction totaled on that line).

Comment: Where do you see that text? I don't see the text "by time" anywhere on the page?

Answer (score 6):

You are sorting the reputation page by **time** - you seem to be expecting it to behave the way it does when sorting by **post**.

Make sure to sort by **post**:

[image: post sort]

Comment: Interesting… that’s wierd.  Indeed “by post” shows multiple events expanding, but in a different order.  Maybe I was seeing a bug *before*!  Though it doesn't seem correct to show a time for a group like that.  Showing each one separately or with explicit grouper made more sense.